# Tufte like axis with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, tufte, axis

How to achieve this kind of axis with pgfplot ? Image taken from Szymon Beczkowski's awesome PhD thesis design ([thesis link](https://vbn.aau.dk/en/publications/control-and-driving-methods-for-led-based-intelligent-light-sourc))

[image: Credit to Beczkowski, Szymon]

I may provide you with some data to play with.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$L$ [H]},ylabel={$\hat{I}_{DM}$ [A]},axis lines*=left,grid,xtick=data]
  \addplot coordinates {(948e-6,1.61981) (1.5e-3,1.02377) (2e-3,0.769047) (2.5e-3,0.614994) (3e-3,0.503511)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This thesis is truly amazing. Is there a TeX source for it?

Comment: Ask the author. I'd be very interested as well.

Comment: Here is the main source file http://pastebin.com/7dPDyucr and also the whole project so you can build it yourself (tables, graphics and bibliography) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/487668/Thesis.zip Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: @SzymonBęczkowski Nice thesis! Can you maybe re-upload the `Thesis.zip` (it seems to be offline)?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zeabfaro8umwwm0/Thesis.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can shift your axes, ticks and labels to obtain the axis effect.  Adjusting the color of the plot and the size of the marks, gets you closer to the general style.  Labels may be added via nodes referencing points in the data coordinate system.

I have updated my previous answer to include new features of `pgfplots` and placed much of the code in a single `tuftelike` style.  Many thanks to Christian Feuersänger for his continued work on the `pgfplots` package.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/tuftelike/.style={
  semithick,
  tick style={major tick length=4pt,semithick,black},
  separate axis lines,
  axis x line*=bottom,
  axis x line shift=10pt,
  xlabel shift=10pt,
  axis y line*=left,
  axis y line shift=10pt,
  ylabel shift=10pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin/.style={red!50!black,font=\small\sffamily}]
  \begin{axis}[tuftelike,
    xlabel={$L$ [H]},
    ylabel={$\hat{I}_{DM}$ [A]},
    enlarge x limits=false,
    xtick=data,
    ytick={0.4,0.6,...,1.801},
    ymin=0.4,ymax=1.8]
    \addplot[black,mark=*,mark size=1.5pt]
    coordinates{(948e-6,1.61981) (1.5e-3,1.02377) (2e-3,0.769047)
    (2.5e-3,0.614994) (3e-3,0.503511)};
    \node[coordinate,pin=above right:{2007}] at (axis cs:1.5e-3,1.02377) {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The form of the axis is obtained by using `separate axis lines` and the `axis ... line*` styles.  Axis shifting is obtained via the `axis ... line shift` and `...label shift` commands.  These could be issued as one common command, but I have kept the `x` and `y` variants visible should you need to change them individually.  Adjustment of tick styling and color is from the `semithick` and the `tick style`.

(The last `ytick` value is `1.801` instead of `1.8` because of rounding problems in the internal arithmetic.)

The code

```
[every pin/.style={red!50!black,font=\small\sffamily}]
```

provides the style for the label of the given point on the graph.

Comment: Any option to get the "tick lines" same as the axis lines ?

Comment: @s__C Code added at end.

Comment: I think if you test it with `scaled y ticks=base 10:2` you'll see the 10^-2 is badly positioned. Any fix?

Comment: @s__C You can add `every y tick scale label/.append style={xshift=-#1}` to the definition of the `y axis shift left/.style`.

Comment: The line width of the last tick is related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91517/how-to-make-the-tick-thickness-as-the-axis-line

Comment: @AndrewSwann Setting `(x/y)tick = data` and `enlarge (x/y) limits = false` produces very nice range frames. However,  when there are a lot of data points, the `(x/y)tick = data` approach causes overlapping tick labels.
I cannot figure out a non-manual way to show the x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max ticks when `(x/y)tick = data` is not used. Do you?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Can you post a new question, showing your set-up etc.?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I managed to to that mixing the macros described in https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-2/tb107dugge.pdf :)

Comment: Note that you can use a new `pgfplots` feature in order to shift lines with all ticks and descriptions: `axis line shift=15pt`.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Excellent! Answer updated to use this.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to shifting the axis, you can go one step further and create what Tufte calls "range frames", where the axis lines only cover the range of the data. One way of doing this is described in [Creating Tufte-style bar charts and scatterplots using PGFPlots](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-2/tb107dugge.pdf) in [TUGBoat issue 34](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-2/) :

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotsdataxmin{\pgfplots@data@xmin}
\def\pgfplotsdataxmax{\pgfplots@data@xmax}
\def\pgfplotsdataymin{\pgfplots@data@ymin}
\def\pgfplotsdataymax{\pgfplots@data@ymax}
\makeatother

\pgfplotsset{
    range frame/.style={
        tick align=outside,
        axis line style={opacity=0},
        after end axis/.code={
            \draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmin,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,0});
            \draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,\pgfplotsdataymin}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,\pgfplotsdataymax});
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    range frame,
    xlabel={$L$ [H]},
    ylabel={$\hat{I}_{DM}$ [A]},
    axis lines*=left,
    xtick=data, ymin=0.41
]
  \addplot +[black, mark options=fill=black] coordinates {(948e-6,1.61981) (1.5e-3,1.02377) (2e-3,0.769047) (2.5e-3,0.614994) (3e-3,0.503511)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my code, if you just specify `enlarge y limits=false` instead of  `yticks, ymax, ymin` you get the same output.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Good point!

Comment: I tried to use all the solutions. This one is working except for one point: the `axis line style={opacity=0}` seems to have no effect, therefore masking the frame.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin: What version of TikZ and PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: Package: tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)

Package: pgfplots 2014/02/28 v1.10 Data Visualization (1.10-2-gb39fe75)

I recently updated to TeXlive 2014

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin: Hm, that should work. So the output you get looks different from the one in my screenshot? Could you maybe open a new question for this?

Comment: I checked: it does not work in my current document (conflict between packages?), while the standalone example works properly

Answer (score 12):

Pgfplots allows a very fine axis customization thanks to options like:

- `x/y/z axis line style`
- `x/y/ztick style`
- `x/yt/zticklabel style`

Basically, if you shift elements in a proper manner, you can achieve something similar. An humble attempt intended as proof of concept:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{axis}[extra description/.code={% to place xlabel and ylabel more arbitrarily
  \node[below=7pt] at ([xshift=1.5cm]xticklabel* cs:1){$L$ [H]};
  \node at ([xshift=-1.5cm]yticklabel* cs:0.5){$\hat{I}_{DM}$ [A]};
  },
  axis x line=left,
  axis y line=left,
  y axis line style={xshift=-6pt,-},
  x axis line style={yshift=-6pt,-},
  xtick style={yshift=-4pt,black}, % black to override the default style
  ytick style={xshift=-4pt,black}, % black to override the default style
  xticklabel style={yshift=-5pt},
  yticklabel style={xshift=-5pt},  
  scaled ticks=false,
  ymin=0.5,
  ymax=1.75,
  ytick={0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75},
  yticklabels={0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75},
  xmin=0.9e-3,
  xmax=3.2e-3,
  xtick={0.9e-3,1.4e-3,2e-3,2.6e-3,3.2e-3},
  xticklabels={0.9e-3,1.4e-3,2e-3,2.6e-3,3.2e-3}]
  \addplot coordinates {(948e-6,1.61981) (1.5e-3,1.02377) (2e-3,0.769047) (2.5e-3,0.614994) (3e-3,0.503511)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]