# Tufte style range frames for three dimensional plots

Tags: pgfplots, tufte

This question is a follow up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155194/tufte-like-axis-with-pgfplots), that allowed me to solve the two dimensional case.

For example this plot

[image: sine]

is created by the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{360pt}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/x axis shift down/.style={
  x axis line style={yshift=-#1},
  xtick style={yshift=-#1},
  xticklabel shift={#1}}}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/y axis shift left/.style={
  y axis line style={xshift=-#1},
  ytick style={xshift=-#1},
  yticklabel shift={#1}}}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={thick},tick style={thick,black},
  range frame/.style={
    tick align=outside,
    scaled ticks=false,
    axis lines*=left,
    enlargelimits=false,
    x axis shift down=10pt,
    y axis shift left=10pt,
    line cap=round,
    clip=false,
    after end axis/.code={
       \draw (xticklabel* cs:0,10pt) -- ++(0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length});
       \draw (xticklabel* cs:1,10pt) -- ++(0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length});
       \draw (yticklabel* cs:0,10pt) -- ++(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length},0);
       \draw (yticklabel* cs:1,10pt) -- ++(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length},0);
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[range frame,xtick={0,90,180,270,360}]
    \addplot[domain=0:360,samples=201] {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Similarly

[image: pdf]

is created by:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{360pt}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/x axis shift down/.style={
  x axis line style={yshift=-#1},
  xtick style={yshift=-#1},
  xticklabel shift={#1}}}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/y axis shift left/.style={
  y axis line style={xshift=-#1},
  ytick style={xshift=-#1},
  yticklabel shift={#1}}}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={thick},tick style={thick,black},
  range frame/.style={
    tick align=outside,
    scaled ticks=false,
    axis lines*=left,
    enlargelimits=false,
    x axis shift down=10pt,
    y axis shift left=10pt,
    line cap=round,
    clip=false,
    after end axis/.code={
       \draw (xticklabel* cs:0,10pt) -- ++(0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length});
       \draw (xticklabel* cs:1,10pt) -- ++(0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length});
       \draw (yticklabel* cs:0,10pt) -- ++(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length},0);
       \draw (yticklabel* cs:1,10pt) -- ++(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length},0);
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[range frame,ytick={0},extra y ticks={0.398942},extra y tick labels={$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}}$},xtick=\empty,extra x ticks={-3,-2,-1,1,2,3},extra x tick labels={$-3σ$,$-2σ$,$-σ$,$σ$,$2σ$,$3σ$}]
    \addplot[domain=-5:5,samples=201,name path=A] {exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
    \path[name path=B] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
    \addplot[black!30] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={(axis cs:-3,0) rectangle (axis cs:3,1)}];
    \addplot[black!20] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={(axis cs:-2,0) rectangle (axis cs:2,1)}];
    \addplot[black!10] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={(axis cs:-1,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,1)}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to achieve the same range frame axis style in a three dimensional plot. My best attempt is:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{360pt}
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={thick},tick style={thick,black},
  range3frame/.style={
    tick align=outside,
    scaled ticks=false,
    enlargelimits=false,
    ticklabel shift={10pt},
    axis lines*=left,
    line cap=round,
    clip=false
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={55}{45}]
    \addplot3[mesh,samples=41,domain=0:360] {sin(x)*sin(y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[range3frame,view={55}{45}]
    \addplot3[mesh,samples=41,domain=0:360] {sin(x)*sin(y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image: sineXtimessineY]

The option `ticklabel shift={10pt}`, does exactly the right thing for the tick mark labels. p. 286 of the pgfplots manual states:

> Shifts tick labels in direction of the outer unit normal of the axis
>   by an amount of ...

Compare the two versions of the sin(x)sin(y)-plot above, the tick mark labels in the lower plot moved away from the axis just right.

Unfortunately there is no `tickmark shift` option to shift the tick marks along the outer unit normal vector in the same way. And also no `axis shift` option to offset the axis.

In the two dimensional solution the trick was to use `xshift` and `yshift` transformation in the `x axis line style` to simply shift the axis and in the `xtick style` to shift the tick marks.

Is there a way to access the outer unit normal vector from the `tickmark shift` option and use a transformation to move the axis and the tickmarks in the same way as the tickmark labels?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT**

Recent versions of `pgfplots` come with `axis line shift`, which allows us to simplify the style as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{360pt}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={thick},tick style={thick,black},
  %
  range3frame/.style={
    tick align=outside,
    scaled ticks=false,
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis lines*=left,
    line cap=round,
    clip=false,
    axis line shift=10pt,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[range3frame,view={55}{45}]
    \addplot3[mesh,samples=41,domain=0:360] {sin(x)*sin(y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

End of edit

---

There is no such predefined style.

But here is one defined in 5 lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{360pt}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={thick},tick style={thick,black},
  %
  % #1 = x, y, or z
  % #2 = the shift value
  /tikz/normal shift/.code 2 args={%
    \pgftransformshift{%
        \pgfpointscale{#2}{\pgfplotspointouternormalvectorofticklabelaxis{#1}}%
    }%
  },%
  %
  range3frame/.style={
    tick align=outside,
    scaled ticks=false,
    enlargelimits=false,
    ticklabel shift={10pt},
    axis lines*=left,
    line cap=round,
    clip=false,
    xtick style={normal shift={x}{10pt}},
    ytick style={normal shift={y}{10pt}},
    ztick style={normal shift={z}{10pt}},
    x axis line style={normal shift={x}{10pt}},
    y axis line style={normal shift={y}{10pt}},
    z axis line style={normal shift={z}{10pt}},
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[range3frame,view={55}{45}]
    \addplot3[mesh,samples=41,domain=0:360] {sin(x)*sin(y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The command `\pgfplotspointouternormalvectorofticklabelaxis{x}` is a shortcut for `\pgfplotspointouternormalvectorofaxis{\pgfplotsticklabelaxisspec{x}}`. I fear the documentation for `\pgfplotspointouternormalvectorofticklabelaxis` is missing in the reference manual.

Note that this shift is incompatible with the grid lines (by construction!). To see this, try to add `grid=major` and you will see the the descriptions are slightly off. You may need to decide if that is what you want (or how to repair it).