# What is this glitch in pgfplots? Plot seems cropped

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

I have this plot generated following the answers proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155194/tufte-like-axis-with-pgfplots/).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/x axis shift down/.style={
    x axis line style={yshift=-#1},
    xtick style={yshift=-#1},
    xticklabel shift={#1}}}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/y axis shift left/.style={
    y axis line style={xshift=-#1},
    ytick style={xshift=-#1},
    yticklabel shift={#1}}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={semithick,tick style={major tick
length=4pt,semithick,black}}}    

\pgfplotsset{
    range frame/.style={
        tick align=outside,
        axis lines*=left,  
        separate axis lines,
        x axis shift down=10pt,
        y axis shift left=10pt,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        enlarge y limits=false,
        }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    range frame,
    title={Axial ratio},
    xlabel={frequency, GHz},
    ylabel={dB},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=3},
    xtick=data,
    ytick=data,
]
    \addplot[black,mark=*,smooth] coordinates {(37.0,0.67534604814572) (37.1,0.66594092733667)
(37.2,0.66026355025028)
(37.3,0.65812677526894)
(37.4,0.65927865540192)
(37.5,0.66342752821752)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Everything works fine, except for this little glitch:

[image]

What's the reason behind it?

Comment: Could it be that this is just an aliasing effect between the graphic and you computer display's resolution? Does it persist at different zoom levels? Does it also show up if the plot is printed?

Comment: Just tried it out myself, and it *is* persistent through zoom levels and seems related to the `x axis shift down` directive.

Comment: That happens because using Andrew's approach, the axis lines are shifted but the clip boundary isn't enlarged. You can fix the problem in this case by setting `clip=false`. Note that this won't work if you actually need the clipping feature, though.

Comment: Thank you all! Actually a duplicate, `clip=false` solves the problem.