# Bar graphs with tikz scientific axes=clean

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-datavisualization

I really like theaxis generated by `tikz datavisualization` with `scientific axes=clean`. However I can not find a bar graph visualizer in the documentation. Does such a visualizer exist? Or (even better) is it possible to format the axis in `pgfplots` accordingly? (I skimmed the manual, but could not find such an option).

[image: Empty graph to show the axes]

Comment: There is [tick align=outside].  What else do you need?

Comment: @JohnKormylo : While `tick align=outside` goes a long way in the right driection I am looking for the separation of the axes and the bar area. Since 1 picture says more than 1000 words, have a look at the picture I added to the question.

Comment: The best you can do is turn off the pgfplots axes [axis x line=none, axis y line=none, name=border] and put you own axes in place.  I've been trying to get \datavisualization to run using the pgfplots xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax and (border) dimensions, but so far no joy.  Frankly it would be easier just to draw and label the axes from scratch.

Comment: @JohnKormylo If I understand the idea correctly `datavisualization` draws the axes and `pgfplots` does the plot?

Comment: That was the idea.  But it seems easier just to use datavisualization to do everything.  Or you could draw and label the axis using regular tikz commands.

Comment: I guess [Tufte like axis with pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155194) is of interest.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. : indeed very interesting, thank you very much.