# How to shift x-axis with labels in xy plane?

Tags: tkz-collection

How to shift x-axis with labels in xy plane?. I tried by this code, but failed. it moves the x-line but their corresponding labels are not in the correct place.

```
  \documentclass[]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,tkz-base}   

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=10,ymax=10,xstep=1,ystep=1] 
    \tkzAxeX[label=,xshift=2cm]
    \tkzAxeY[label=]

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I need to shift x and y lines with their labels.

Comment: I haven't fully understood your question, do you want something like the axes that go from -2 to 10 and intersect at (0,0) or simply shift the picture position in the page or what else? Could you edit your post adding a photo of the manual drawing of what you intend?

Comment: Are you after something like [Tufte like axis with pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155194)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that: "removing" the original axis and redraw them.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,tkz-base}    
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}     
\begin{document}        
\begin{tikzpicture}[myaxis/.style={thin, ->, >=stealth, shorten >=-15pt}]

\tkzInit[xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=10, ymax=10, xstep=1, ystep=1]     
\tkzAxeY[label=,style={very thin,opacity=0}]        
\tkzAxeX[label=,xshift=2cm, style={very thin,opacity=0}]        
\draw [myaxis] (2,0) -- (12, 0);
\draw [myaxis] (0,0) -- (0,10);
\end{tikzpicture}            
\end{document}
```

[image: Move X-Axis]