# How to put fancy axes around a picture with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I want to add axes around a picture with TikZ as shown in the following image. I think I can handle positioning the axes, but how can I set them to have this kind of look, rather than being just usual axes ?

[image: Wanted output]

Thank you for your advices

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your specific problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Plain TikZ, or `pgfplots`? If the latter, perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155194/tufte-like-axis-with-pgfplots?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This is exactly this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) to draw the axes and include the image with `\addplot graphics`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = left,
            axis line style = -,
            axis line shift = 2mm,
            every tick/.append style = {black, thin},
            tick align = outside,
            unit markings = parenthesis,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            x unit = {m},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            y unit = {m}
        ]
        \addplot graphics [
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 4,
            ymin = -2,
            ymax = 2
        ]
            {example-image-a};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Great answer, but why the super old PGFPlots? - newest is `1.18`

Comment: Thanks. `1.6` is indeed a bit old - no special reason for that. I updated the version to `1.18` now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic setup you can adjust to your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\fill (0,-2) rectangle (4,2); 
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2mm]
\draw (0,-2) --node[yshift=-9mm]{$\mathsf{x(m)}$} (4,-2);
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}{\draw (\x,-2)--(\x,-2.2) node[below]{\x};}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2mm]
\draw (0,-2) --node[yshift=9mm, sloped]{$\mathsf{y(m)}$} (0,2);
\foreach \y in {-2,...,2}{\draw (0,\y)--(-.2,\y) node[left]{\y};}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```